# change div width every second

Tags: html, width, transition

I have googled this question, can't find an answer so hope someone can help me out.

Basicly what I'm trying to get is a kind of a timer. A div that has a 100% width and gets smaller every second until it reaches 0% after a specific given amount of time. So lets say it decreases from 100% to 0% over 5 minutes.

I don't know how this could be done, simply css or php or javascript. Can this be done using onenterframe and css transitions? What's the best way to achieve this (or something like)?

Answer (score 0):

change width or move?
use

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
```

in css

Comment: what's the use of the `z-index` in my question? I don't need it to be on top or whatsoever, I'm looking for a script (or other kind of way) to change the width every second, without having the page to reload. So after 1 second `width=100%` after 2 seconds `width=99%`, after 3 seconds `width=98%` etc. etc.